# Problem in progresive wave

Tags: waves

[In this  progressive wave](http://www.parrswood.manchester.sch.uk/faculties/science/images/wav_6.gif)  we need to find out the phase difference. If we define it by $\phi$  in the x distance, we get .
$$\phi = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}x$$
But when we write the prograsive wave equation we , write as,

$$y= A \sin (\omega t - \phi)$$
A author says that this phase difference is less than the phase difference in the left side.

My problem is, we can insert also + sign. But what is the physics for inserting the plus or minus sign.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A wave packet/train of the form $f(x\mp v t)$ is a $\begin{array}{c}\text{right}\\ \text{left}\end{array} $ mover with velocity $\pm v$, respectively.

How do we deduce which sign is which? Well, pick some fixed argument, e.g. $0$, of the wave profile $f$. Let us observe this section of the wave profile, where it takes the value $f(0)$. We want to ride with this portion of the profile as the wave packet/train moves forward in time $t>0$. To keep the argument fixed $x\mp v t=0$ at zero, we would have to change our position $x=\pm vt$ as time $t>0$ passes. In other words, we would move to the $\begin{array}{c}\text{right}\\ \text{left}\end{array}$.

Comment: I wanted to  know why $-$ sign is the right mover?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the physics or better the mathematics of a plus or minus sign is, that for a minus sign (or better said for a different sign between the time-term and the spatial-term) the wave propagates to the right (assuming "right" means " bigger x")

you can see this by insterting t=0, draw y(x) and then inserting t=some small value and draw y(x) again.

in general f(x-x0) is the same as f(x) just moved to the RIGHT by x0.
if you problems in imagine this, really just make a sketch (over the same x-axis!) of a y=f(x) and a moved counterpart and ask: what are the y-values at x=0 in both cases